# Firefox gBrowser.getBrowserForTab but no gBrowser.getTabForBrowser?

Tags: browser, tabs, firefox-addon

In the Javascript for a Firefox extension, you can call `gBrowser.getBrowserForTab` but there is no `gBrowser.getTabForBrowser`. So I wrote my own and it works, and I'm just curious if there's any reason I shouldn't be doing this, or if there's anything wrong with the code. The following is in my `init` method that gets called when the window loads.

```
gBrowser.getTabForBrowser = function(browser) {
  for (var i=0; i<gBrowser.browsers.length; i++) {
    if (gBrowser.getBrowserAtIndex(i) === browser) {
      return gBrowser.tabContainer.getItemAtIndex(i);
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

(or should it be `gBrowser.prototype.getTabForBrowser = ...`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Far as I know there is no built in `getTabForBrowser` function, so you would have to roll your own. However, your code assumes that browser nodes are stored in the same DOM order as tab nodes. I can't say for sure if this assumption is ever broken, but considering tabs can be re-positioned by the user arbitrarily, it is not something I'd rely on.

Fortunately, each tab object has a `linkedBrowser` property. So you could rewrite your code like so:

```
gBrowser.getTabForBrowser = function(browser) {
  var mTabs = gBrowser.mTabContainer.childNodes;
  for (var i=0, i<mTabs.length; i++) {
    if (mTabs[i].linkedBrowser == browser) {
      return mTabs[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Should it be `==` or `===`? I think it's conceivable that two `<browser>`s would compare as equal even though they aren't exactly the same browser, although I'm not sure. So `===` seems safer to me.

Comment: After some quick experimenting, it looks like it *does* reorder the browsers in the DOM, but you're right that I shouldn't rely on that. Good point!

Comment: `a === b` is equivilent to `typeof a == typeof b && a == b`, so when the types of both operands are already known to be the same, `===` is not necessary. Since objects in Javascript are assigned to variables by reference, two distinct objects will never compare equally even if they contain the same property names and values. `({x:5}) == ({x:5})` evaluates to `false`. That being said, `===` certainly does not hurt, and it has the advantage that you don't have to think about it too hard.